# Vite, Vue и доступ к компонентам

Tags: vue.js, авторизация, компоненты, vite

В разрабатываемом приложении есть 3 области:

- меню;
- настройщик даты открытой формы;
- область размещения форм (ОРФ).

ОРФ представляет собой панель вкладок, в которых размещаются формы.

Под словом "форма" подразумеваем vue-компоненты, содержащий любые теги (как правило редактируемая таблица с данными).

При нажатии на пункт меню в ОРФ размещается вкладка с заданным компонентом. Компонент загружается динамически и использует текущую дату, указанную в настройщике.

Во Vue используются компоненты и страницы (представления). Думаю, что данное приложение ориентировано на компоненты, а не страницы.

В качестве сборщика задействован Vite. По умолчанию Vite помещает компоненты в папку dist/assets. Названия таких компонентов содержат hash.

**Вопрос:** В случае страниц при авторизации во Vue применяются роутеры. Как в случае компонентов ограничивать доступ пользователя к динамически подключаемым компонентам в production?

Comment: Так у вас же есть хук жизненного компонента created? и есть какая-то переменная в стейте, которая определяет, что пользователь авторизирован.
В каждом компоненте проверяйте эту переменную и если пользователь не авторизирован, то пуште на страницу авторизации.
this.$router.push({ name: "Login" })
Если нужно подробнее, то уже в ответе распишу, но мне кажется, что все понятно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В приложении страницы не используются, только компоненты, которые динамически подгружаются с сервера. Вопрос был в том, как защитить файл от загрузки клиенту, если у него нет прав?
Я начинаю думать, что в этом нет необходимости, т. к. защита должна быть сосредоточена на API сервера, который выдает данные.